# How to prevent API abuse from Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This function takes an access token as an argument, and uses it to create a google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials object. It then uses the credentials object to create a googleapiclient.discovery.Resource object for the Google People API, and uses it to make a request to retrieve the current user's email address. The email address is returned as a string.

```
import google.auth
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def get_user_email(access_token):
    credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(info={}, token=access_token)
    service = build('people', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    person = service.people().get(resourceName='people/me', personFields='emailAddresses').execute()
    email = person['emailAddresses'][0]['value']
    return email
```

Comment: Can you characterize the service the API itself is providing? What risk is there if someone were to hit the endpoints in question with regenerated client IDs that differs from a large amount of users installing and using the extension in question near-simultaneously?

Comment: The plugin is one that counts and aggregates user actions. If people were to send requests with random client IDs, it would mess up all the aggregates.

Comment: @Jabrove You're going to have to do some heuristics to figure out if the data is good or not.

Comment: All of your efforts should be on making the server more resilient, which you want to do anyways. If all you have is a rate limiter, then you still have more protection to add. You're on a wild goose chase if you want to try to hide things from the user on client-side, especially in a web browser context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using OAuth2.

On extension install, I get the user to login with through Chrome.

Then I fetch their auth token and send it with each API request like this:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
   headers =  {
                    // some other headers
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
              }
   // send an API request with the headers above
}
```

Then on the server side (Python), I hit the Google userinfo API and pass the token to get access to the data I need:

```
response = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo", params={"access_token": auth_token_from_request})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like with anything else on the client (browser extension, or otherwise), **you can't**.

Not directly anyway.

Think of it this way...  If someone whom you've never met knocks on your door and says, "Hi, I'm Joe Josepheson", you have to choose whether to believe them or not.  If it doesn't really matter who they are, then you might believe their name.  On the other hand, suppose you're expecting a baby sitter to show up... would you leave your kids with someone who just claimed to be who they said they were?  Probably not... you'd want some sort of other evidence.

I assume your website has some sort of an account login system?  If so, you'll have to get the user to log in at some point.  And then, store a session ID, cookie, JWT, some way to identify that user later on.  Then when subsequent API requests come in, you can associate them with the correct user account (or at least someone impersonating that account).

Keep in mind though, you can't prevent that user from making arbitrary API calls against your service.  That's impossible.